# Mariadb can't be installed on my Debian, why?

Tags: apt, dependencies, mariadb

Because I like to have my own DB, I tried to install MariaDB.

Here are the steps I used:

```sh
apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client # Just to be safe that mysql isn't there
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install mariadb-server
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://mirror.netcologne.de/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian jessie main'
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install mariadb-server
```

But finally it throws this error: 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 10.3.5+maria~stretch) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: So, from your text can I infer the following? You are using some sort of Ubuntu distribution and want to install maria DB from an external repository which appears to hold packages for Debian/jessie. Have you checked whether your distro is compatible with debian/jessie? Does ubuntu's repositories also provide mariadb-server? If they do, you want to run your apt-get install against the external repository with '-t jessie' or whatever the repository ended up being called under sources.d.

Comment: Kali problems....